# How can I evaluate a boolean expression string in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, boolean-logic

I have a string with the following value:

```
COND_STRING = '(TRUE AND FALSE AND TRUE) OR FALSE'
```

How can I evaluate the outcome if it is True or False (1 or 0) in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This is tricky, given that SQL Server doesn't support booleans.  You can do:

```
declare @new_cond = replace(replace(@cond_string, 'TRUE', '(1=1)'), 'FALSE', '(1=0)');

declare @sql = 'select @result = (case when @cond then 1 else 0 end)';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@cond', @new_cond);

declare @result int;

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int output', @result=@result output;
```

Answer (score 2):

i can only think of this way. Using `Dynamic SQL`

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '(TRUE AND FALSE AND TRUE) OR FALSE'

select  @str = replace(replace(replace(replace(@str, 'TRUE', '1'), 'FALSE', 0), 'AND', '&'), 'OR', '|')

select  @str    = 'SELECT' + @str

print   @str
exec    (@str)
```